# Why does my query returns empty result while using JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql

Why does my query returns empty result!

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM `BANDS` INNER JOIN `adres`
ON `BANDS`.BOEKERID = `adres`
WHERE VIS='ja' ";
```

VIS is filled with ja

when i remove either  WHERE VIS='ja or ON `BANDS`.BOEKERID = `adres`

it works i get results

Comment: Do you habe a column `adres` in table `adres` that matches `BOEKERID`?

Comment: What are you joining the adres table on? you should join it on for example adres.boek_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join on a specific column that is the same in both the tables.

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM `BANDS
INNER JOIN `adres` ON `BANDS`.BOEKERID=`adres`.boek_id
```

WHERE adres.VIS='ja'";

also, it might be better to prefix the VIS field like    WHERE adres.VIS='ja' or WHERE BANDS.VIS='ja'";

Comment: This works, thks a lot